# Why keybindings in my neovim LSP configuration file does not working?

Tags: lua, neovim, nvim-lspconfig

```
local M = {}

-- TODO: backfill this to template
M.setup = function()
  local signs = {
    { name = "DiagnosticSignError", text = "" },
    { name = "DiagnosticSignWarn", text = "" },
    { name = "DiagnosticSignHint", text = "" },
    { name = "DiagnosticSignInfo", text = "" },
  }

  for _, sign in ipairs(signs) do
    vim.fn.sign_define(sign.name, { texthl = sign.name, text = sign.text, numhl = _ })
  end

  local config = {
    -- disable virtual text
    virtual_text = false,
    -- show signs
    signs = {
      active = signs,
    },
    update_in_insert = true,
    underline = true,
    severity_sort = true,
    float = {
      focusable = false,
      style = "minimal",
      border = "rounded",
      source = "always",
      header = "",
      prefix = "",
    },
  }

  vim.diagnostic.config(config)

  vim.lsp.handlers["textDocument/hover"] = vim.lsp.with(vim.lsp.handlers.hover, {
    border = "rounded",
  })

  vim.lsp.handlers["textDocument/signatureHelp"] = vim.lsp.with(vim.lsp.handlers.signature_help, {
    border = "rounded",
  })
end

local function lsp_highlight_document(client)
  -- Set autocommands conditional on server_capabilities
  if client.resolved_capabilities.document_highlight then
    vim.api.nvim_exec(
      [[
      augroup lsp_document_highlight
        autocmd! * <buffer>
        autocmd CursorHold <buffer> lua vim.lsp.buf.document_highlight()
        autocmd CursorMoved <buffer> lua vim.lsp.buf.clear_references()
      augroup END
    ]],
      false
    )
  end
end

local function lsp_keymaps(bufnr)
  local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "gD", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.declaration()<CR>", opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "gd", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>", opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "K", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>", opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "gi", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.implementation()<CR>", opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "<C-k>", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.signature_help()<CR>", opts)
  -- vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "<leader>rn", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.rename()<CR>", opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "gr", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.references()<CR>", opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "<leader>ca", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()<CR>", opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "<leader>f", "<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.open_float()<CR>", opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "[d", '<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.goto_prev({ border = "rounded" })<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(
    bufnr,
    "n",
    "gl",
    '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.show_line_diagnostics({ border = "rounded" })<CR>',
    opts
  )
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "]d", '<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.goto_next({ border = "rounded" })<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "<leader>q", "<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.setloclist()<CR>", opts)
  vim.cmd [[ command! Format execute 'lua vim.lsp.buf.formatting()' ]]
end

M.on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  lsp_keymaps(bufnr)
  lsp_highlight_document(client)
end

local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()

local status_ok, cmp_nvim_lsp = pcall(require, "cmp_nvim_lsp")
if not status_ok then
  return
end

M.capabilities = cmp_nvim_lsp.update_capabilities(capabilities)

return M
```

This file is part of my lspconfig. LSP itself seems to set up correctly because when I run
`lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()` it works, the problem is that the same command does not work with the keybinding which is declared in this file. None of these keybindings seem to be working. I can't understand what is the problem, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what version of NeoVim you are using. If you are running 0.7 you can change your call

```
vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, ...
```

for

```
vim.keymap.set(mode, shortcut, command, opts)
```

This API allows an additional parameter in opts `buffer`, if you set this value to `true` or `1` it assigns the current buffer to it, or in your situation, you can assign `bufnr` to the buffer opts parameter.

So for the example, you are trying to run, you could write

```
vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', vim.lsp.buf.hover, { buffer = bufnr, noremap = true, silent = true })
```

Also, you should configure the on_attach and capabilities for each of the configurations of your LSP.

e.g. :

```
require('lspconfig')['pyright'].setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  capabilities = capabilities,
}
```

What you are currently doing from my understanding without the context on how this lua file is called, is returning as the setup configuration of `lspconfig` the on_attach and capabilities function without assigning it to any configuration.

Ref : https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig#troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

I have 0.9.4 version of Neovim and vim.api.nvim_set_keymap(mode, shortcut, command, opts) worked for me